# SQLite table not displaying data on activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I have successfully created a database table with SQlite.However when i try to use a custom adapter to display the data in rows,the activity is blank,as in it does not display the data i saved into it.

This is how i get data from my data base in **DBHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper**

```js
public ArrayList<ContactListItems> getAllContacts() {
        ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
            ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

            contactListItems.setTitle(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex("title")));
            contactListItems.setAmount(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex("amount")));
            contactListItems.setDescription(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex("description")));
            res.moveToNext();
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }

        return contactList;
    }
```

And in **MyBasket** Activity,this is how i display the data with **ContactListAdapter**:

```js
 private void showTable() {
        ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList = myDb.getAllContacts();

        ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(
                MyBasket.this, contactList);
        //adding it to the list view.
obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);
    }
```

**ContactListItems:**

```js
public class ContactListItems {
    String title;
    String amount;
    String description;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

ContactListAdapter:

```js
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactListItems> list) {

        this.context = context;
        contactList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ContactListItems contactListItems = contactList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_row, null);

        }
        TextView tvSlNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_slno);
        tvSlNo.setText(contactListItems.getTitle());
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvName.setText(contactListItems.getAmount());
        TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
        tvPhone.setText(contactListItems.getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The code runs fine with no errors but no display of data.I really do not see where i have gone wrong.Any assistance will be appreciated and if you need more code let me know.

**Edit**
So as to understand better
When i was using this code:

```js
private void showTable() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = myDb.getAllContacts();

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

        //adding it to the list view.
        obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

And this :

```js
public ArrayList<String> getAllContacts() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
        hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            array_list.add("Product: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TITLE)));
            array_list.add("Amount: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT)));
            array_list.add("Description: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESC)));
            System.out.print("database data:" + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TITLE)));
            System.out.print("database data:" + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT)));
            System.out.print("database data:" + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESC)));
            System.out.print("List holds:" + array_list);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
```

The data was being displayed properly but i wanted to customize the rows insted of using the arraylist.

Comment: Please share contactListAdapter too.  Can you check that you do have some values in the db..

Comment: @Kay yes i do have the values in my database.On my OnCreate() ,if i db is empty it displays an alert dialog.Now it doesnt.  `if (myDb.checkForTables()) {
            showTable();
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            showAlert();
            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }`

Comment: add `contactList.add( contactListItems)`, and remove `res.moveToNext();`  in `getAllContacts()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in getAllContacts()

You missed out on :

```
 contactList.add( contactListItems)
```

in the if block.

Basically you are returning contactList object with valid memory reference and empty data.

Comment: If it isnt any trouble,instead of asking on a different thread yet it is related,i was trying to return the number of rows from my database to show on my activity.This is what i have tried.In my database:`public int numberOfRows() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  contacts ", null);
        int x = 0;
        if (cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            x = cur.getInt(0);
        }
        cur.close();
        return x;
    }`

Comment: ` TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numRows);
       myDb.numberOfRows();
        txt.setText(Integer.toString(numRows));` but the value returned is always zero.

Comment: This is returning value of first column.  getInt(int columnIndex) will return value of first column in database via cursor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75062/discussion-between-steve-kamau-and-kay).